# Search for text defined in constant in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm dissecting some horrendous application, and part of my task is to find where the data for some database rows is coming from.  I know what the names of the columns are, and the application uses `public static final String`s defined in a shared, compiled .jar to refer to them. My goal is to find the actual constant String object that defines the column, and use Eclipse's call hierarchy feature to work backwards and find where it's being used.

However, a "Java search" isn't working because it only looks at field/type names, not values, and a basic text or file search isn't working because the constants are in a compiled ".class" file. The field names don't line up very either (`public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER = "customerId";`) so it's very hard to actually find them.

Is there a search feature in Eclipse that searches for string constant values?  I'm using Eclipse 3.8 (Indigo).

Answer (score 0):

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

You should try this to decompile your jar so you can search through it, but it won't exactly help if it's obfuscated. I hope it helps you though!